# Xorg taking huge amounts of memory

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, memory, memory-leaks

Lately, there is a lot of memory leak on my (Arch) Linux laptop. A command named `Xorg -nolisten tcp :0 vt1 --keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.mWgFYYiRdF` is continually taking 27.2 % of my 8GB RAM (also around 2G is consumed of swap).

How do I troubleshoot ? (I use no login manager, just `startx`

Comment: Are you sure it is a problem? Remember that used RAM isn't a bad thing (see https://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

Comment: @terdon Yeh it is because it has begin only some time ago.

Comment: Any clue on this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about RSS/RES or VIRT? If it's the former, you might have a memory leak somewhere (most likely in GPU drivers), if it's VIRT - don't even pay attention to it.

> How do I troubleshoot ?

Try updating your kernel and the Mesa stack. If no updates are available, file a bug report.

- Intel: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues
- AMD: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues

Comment: VIRT: 3263M, RES: 2064M
My kernel is latest Linux-zen 5.9.8

Comment: RES could indicate a major memory leak. I'd file a bug report.